# $(pwd) - one level up

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

I'm pretty new to the bash/shell script world, I'm trying to do the below and it could be pretty simple but I wasn't able to figure out the command, would be great if someone could help me out here and also point me to some documentation wrt to shell script topics. Thank you in advance.

My build.sh and Dockerfile resides under a folder called .settings and this folder lives directly under the app root. Now inside my build.sh and Dockerfile when I refer something like $(pwd) or COPY . /apps/ it might not work since my build.sh and Dockerfile does not live directly under the app root.

What command I can use in this scenario inside the files that I referenced above. Hope I made it clear. Once again this could be very simple since I'm a newbie in this arena I find it a little difficult.

```
inside build.sh, reference to $(pwd)

docker run \
-u root \
--rm \
-v $(pwd):/app \ ----> this $(pwd) references the application root, but if I 
move this build.sh inside a folder called .settings then the $(pwd) context 
would change and I still want to refer it to the root.
<MYIMAGE NAME FROM LOCAL REPO>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question but does `echo "${PWD%/*}"` give you what you want? It won't work if you're at the root of your filesystem :)

Comment: so i'm just trying to achieve the below, in the above example, $(PWD) would log /app/.settings and i would like to change the reference to root from this context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last arg to `docker build`, often something like `docker build .` is the build context in docker. This directory is sent to the server where the build runs and all `COPY` and `ADD` commands are performed using this context. These commands do not run on the client, and docker is a client/server application, so anything not in that context simply doesn't exist for the purpose of building an image.

So in the above example, `docker build .` the current directory is the build context and if that's run while you're inside of the `.settings` directory, only those files are part of the build context. Therefore your `build.sh` script needs to pass a different directory, and also reference where the `Dockerfile` is inside of that build context. That would look like:

```
docker build -f .settings/Dockerfile ..
```

When you do this, all of the `COPY` and `ADD` commands will now be relevant to parent directory, so you may need to adjust your `Dockerfile` to compensate.

---

For your `$(pwd)` reference, you can either `cd ..` before running your `docker run` command or update the command to look like:

```
docker run \
  -u root \
  --rm \
  -v $(pwd)/..:/app \
  <your image>
```

Comment: thank you. i get the your reference, i do have certain references in the build.sh and Dockerfile assuming they were under the root, since these 2 files are going to be living under .settings folder, how can i change those references that uses $(PWD)?, for example right now the $(PWD) consoles out /app/.settings/ and i would lie to change it's reference to /app (considering the root is /app)

Comment: `COPY` and `ADD` are relative to the build context, and cannot see anything further up the tree from that. To copy a file from the .settings directory into the image, it would simply be `COPY .settings/X /image/dir/X`

Comment: got you, one last query, in this scenario how can i change the reference to $(PWD), as i mentioned earlier i do have few references related to $(PWD) and since the build.sh is moved from root to .settings folder the $(PWD) reference would change and i want that reference to go one level up and refer the root

Comment: I'm sure I understand your comment. You should probably include the relevant script in your question.

Comment: Sure, i added to my original query