# Copying a file a level above when using $(pwd)

Tags: bash, unix, cp

I've looked at the following answer which is close to what I'm asking but I can't get the relevant part of the answer working.

[$(pwd) - one level up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888079/pwd-one-level-up#comment76755218_44888349)

I'm working on a script where the author created a variable

```
currentlocation=$(pwd)
```

Then navigates to another folder called scripts and uses `cp -p $currentlocation/* .` to copy all the scripts into the Scripts folder.

I've added a new script in the folder level above currentlocation which I would like to copy to the Scripts folder.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could let me know the line of code to achieve this.

I've tried

```
cp -p $currentlocation/../newScript
```

and

```
cp -p $currentlocation/..:/newScript
```

but no luck so far

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? Does your computer suddenly gets on fire? From your code, I would expect that you get an error message, because the destination parameter is missing, but you don't write that you got one, so I wonder what effect you have observed instead.

Comment: Assuming you are copying to current directory `cp -p $currentlocation/../newScript .`

Comment: what is `newScript`? is it a variable? Is it a target dir? Do you have some error messages?

Comment: I guess you want `cp -p "$currentlocation"/../newScript .` where the second argument `.` indicates where you want to copy it.  Notice also proper quoting.

Comment: Try:  `onelevelupdir=${currentlocation%/*} `  or:  `onelevelupdir=$( dirname "$currentlocation" )`

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I was missing the . at the end of the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to copy the script from the upper directory:

`cp -p ${currentlocation%/*}/newScript .`

In order to get one level up directory, from `currentlocation` variable that contains the current working directory you should remove the last / and everything after it.

Another way of getting one level directory:

`dir=$( dirname "$currentlocation" )` or `dir=$( dirname "$PWD" )`

Anyway, it is not recommended to reference a directory/destination as in your case with "." instead the absolute paths should be used.